# corona sdk scale images

Tags: lua, image, corona-sdk

How to scale images to full screen on all devices, i want to use `%`

The method I've seen so far is to define pixels

`image_variable_name = display.newImage( "testimage.jpg", 100, 300 )`

I want to do something like

`image_variable_name = display.newImage( "testimage.jpg", 100%, 100% )`

But that won't work, I want something like fluid CSS, the image will maintain the size no matter what is the size of the screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `newImageRect()` instead of `newImage()`

```
image_variable_name = display.newImageRect("testimage.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
--then you have to center it: 
image_variable_name.x = display.contentWidth / 2
image_variable_name.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually Corona uses feature called [dynamic scaling](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/) so it let you working within same virtual size - 320х480. You can even have different assets for different scale factors.

Answer (score 1):

Use [display.newImageRect()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html), except unlike [display.newImage()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html), you now have to enter the width and height of the image you are feeding in (the actual file). This will now scale automatically.

Also, if you ever switch to landscape mode for your default orientation, make sure your config.lua still has the fields width and height as if you were in portrait mode. Its a weird gotcha.

Here's how I present a background picture which takes up the full screen of a landscape mode 1280 x 720 display (Galaxy S3):

```
menuBg = display.newImageRect( "images/bg.png", 1280, 720 )
menuBg:setReferencePoint( display.CenterLeftReferencePoint )
menuBg.x = 0
menuBg.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

Setting the reference point is of personal preference, so play with that yourself.